# Custom iterator for value checking

Tags: c++, iterator, std

I am new to iterators and trying gain more knowledge about them.

That's why I'm trying to create a custom iterator to traverse given string array to check if any values of that string is a decimal value or not. I come up with the implementation given below:

Collection is the user of my iterator

```
// Collection type
template <class T, int N>
class Collection
{
    // Holder for our collection
    // N is the size for our collection
    T data[N];

public:

    Collection(T _data[N]) { copy_n(_data, N, data); }

    // Method to return the iterator to the beginning of the collection
    CollectionIterator<T> begin()
    {
        return CollectionIterator<T>(data);
    }
    // Method to return the iterator to the end of the collection
    CollectionIterator<T> end()
    {
        return CollectionIterator<T>(data + N);
    }
};
```

CollectionIterator is my custom iterator (with a type of input iterator)

```
template <class T>
class CollectionIterator
{
    T *data;

public:
    using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;
    using value_type = T;
    using difference_type = size_t;                         
    using pointer = T*;
    using reference = T&;

    // Default constructor
    CollectionIterator(){}
    CollectionIterator(pointer _data): data(_data) {}

    reference operator*()
    {
        if(is_number(*data))
        {
            std::cout << *data;
        }
        return *data;
    }

    bool operator!=(const CollectionIterator &other)
    {
        return data != other.data;
    }

    CollectionIterator<T>& operator++()
    {
        data += 1;
        return *this;
    }

    CollectionIterator<T> operator++(int)
    {
        return CollectionIterator<T>(data + 1);
    }

    bool is_number(const std::string& s)
    {
        return !s.empty() && std::find_if(s.begin(),
            s.end(), [](unsigned char c) { return !std::isdigit(c); }) == s.end();
    }
};
```

Below you can see how I use the collection class.

```
std::string s[8] = { "2", "hello", "world", "asd5", "19870717", "sadsad7", "8", "byby" };

Collection <std::string, 8> test (s);

for (auto t = test.begin(); t != test.end(); t++){ }
```

When I run the code, I would like to see 2 19870717 8 but it doesn't print anything. Am I missing something or is anything wrong in my code?

Comment: You only print in `CollectionIterator::operator*`, but you never dereference an instance of `CollectionIterator`, so `operator*` is never called.

Comment: There are several issues. One is you did not implement the postfix ++ operator correctly (it should return the state of the object *before* the increment), but you should be using the prefix ++ operator with iterators anyway (which is what your operator ++ is doing).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik it doesn't change anything if I use an instance like cout << *t inside the for loop.

Comment: Your post-increment operator doesn't actually increment `data` member, and so you have an infinite loop. In other words, after `auto t = test.begin(); t++;` you still have `t == test.begin()` (or rather, `!(t != test.begin())` since you haven't implemented `operator==`). The example as written, with only `*t` added, [prints `2` forever](https://godbolt.org/z/YcqTG5)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ah I get it. I changed both pre and post increments as below and it works. Is this the correct way to implement?

    CollectionIterator<T>& operator++()
    {
        CollectionIterator i = *this;
        data++;
        return i;
    }

    CollectionIterator<T> operator++(int)
    {
        data++;
        return *this;
    }

Comment: You have them the wrong way round. Your pre-increment operator behaves like post-increment, and vice versa. Also, `operator++()` (the pre-increment) returns a reference to a local variable - an invitation for undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically, my post and pre increment implementation were not correct. When I changed them as below, it works.

```
bool operator==(const CollectionIterator &other)
{
    return data == other.data;
}

CollectionIterator<T>& operator++()
{
    data++;

    return *this;
}

CollectionIterator<T> operator++(int)
{
    CollectionIterator i = *this;

    data++;

    return i;
}
```